# Count repetitions of values in a vector with OpenGL

Tags: c++, ios, opengl-es

I want to parallelize this C code using the GPU in OpenGL ES 2.0 (it is for iOS 7):

```
unsigned char color[3][N]; // RGB
unsigned int count[3][256] = {0};
// fill color matrix...
// Count how many R, G and B values:
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    ++count[0][color[0][i]];
    ++count[1][color[1][i]];
    ++count[2][color[2][i]];
}
```

I'm an OpenGL newbie. I've been thinking that I could set the RGB as the xyz of the vertices, a value of 0x01 as the Alpha, and black as the color (not sure if necessary). Then project the 3D space into 3 planes: xy, xz and yz. And finally project those 3 planes into x, y and z lines, adding the alphas in each of those steps (I guess this is possible). So in line x I'd have vector color[0][256], in y color[1][256] and in z color[2][256]. Being the resultant alpha the value I want. In this case alpha could be much bigger than 256. So I'm not sure it can be so. Not sure it'll work.

Does that looks correct? Is that possible in OpenGL? How can those projections be done (is there a name for that projection)? How can I retrieve that info (count) back to process with the CPU?

Comment: What if there are more than 255 occurrences of the same RGB triple? Then the alpha will be maxed out at that point.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was wondering, if in that case alpha can take bigger values. I guess not.